# Import data using sqoop with $ on the table name

Tags: oracle, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, sqoop

I am encountering an error importing data from Oracle database to hive using sqoop:

Sqoop command below:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@connectionString/Database \
--username USERNAME \
--password-file /path/password/file \
--query "SELECT * FROM \"DBO.LOG$_TEST_TABLE\" WHERE \$CONDITIONS" \
--hcatalog-database HIVE_DB \
--hcatalog-table LOG__TEST_TABLE \
-m 1;
```

Here's the error message after running the command:

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The table exist in the oracle database, but the sql statement used (printed in the screen) is `INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement:  SELECT * FROM DBO.LOG WHERE (1=0)`

The table name has been cut after the '$' of the specified table name.

Comment: Dont think table with $  in name can be imported using sqoop

Answer (score 0):

Already solved the issue by adding \$ in all columns or table name that has $.